# AsyncStorage not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to build a react-native app using Expo, a simple movie app with OMDB api.
Having some problems with AsyncStorage...

Firstly it doesn't seem to save properly... usually it works but then when i completely close the expo app and reload the data doesn't exist again...

and secondly i have a 'poster' component that is shared for displaying movies from a search query and also for movies in my watched list. The button text is supposed to change from 'add' to 'remove' if the object already exists in the watched list.

For some reason it works on the watched list, but not on the search query list.

Heres App.tsx:

```
interface TVPROPS {
  Poster: string;
  Title: string;
  Type: string;
  Year: string;
  imdbID: string;
}

export default function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState<string>("");
  const [tvData, setTVData] = useState([]);
  const [watched, setWatched] = useState<TVPROPS[]>([]);
  const [watchClick, setWatchClick] = useState<Boolean>(false);

  const saveToLocalStorage = async (items: TVPROPS[]) => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("react-watched", JSON.stringify(items));
  };

  const getLocalStorage = async () => {
    const movieFavourites = await AsyncStorage.getItem("react-watched");
    if (movieFavourites !== null) {
      const movieFavouritesParse: TVPROPS[] = JSON.parse(movieFavourites);
      setWatched(movieFavouritesParse);
    }
  };

  const handleSearch = async (searchInput: string) => {
    const response = await axios(
      `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${API_KEY}&s=${searchInput}`
    );
    const data = response.data;
    setTVData(data.Search);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getLocalStorage();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    saveToLocalStorage(watched);
  }, [watched]);

  return (
    <>
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: "grey" }}>
        <View style={{ marginTop: 40 }}>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", padding: 10 }}>
            <View
              style={{
                width: "50%",
                borderBottomWidth: watchClick ? 0 : 1,
                padding: 10,
                borderColor: "white",
              }}
            >
              <Pressable onPress={() => setWatchClick(false)}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    textAlign: "center",
                    color: watchClick ? "black" : "white",
                  }}
                >
                  Search
                </Text>
              </Pressable>
            </View>
            <View
              style={{
                width: "50%",
                borderBottomWidth: watchClick ? 1 : 0,
                padding: 10,
                borderColor: "white",
              }}
            >
              <Pressable onPress={() => setWatchClick(true)}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    textAlign: "center",
                    color: watchClick ? "white" : "black",
                  }}
                >
                  Watched
                </Text>
              </Pressable>
            </View>
          </View>
          <TextInput
            style={{ textAlign: "center" }}
            onChangeText={(text) => setSearch(text)}
            placeholder="Film or TV Show"
          ></TextInput>
          <Button onPress={() => handleSearch(search)} title="Search" />
        </View>
      </View>
      {watchClick ? (
        <ScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            flexWrap: "wrap",
          }}
        >
          {watched
            ?.filter((w) => w.Title.includes(search))
            .map((data: TVPROPS, index: number) => (
              <Poster
                key={index}
                data={data}
                watched={watched}
                setWatched={setWatched}
              />
            ))}
        </ScrollView>
      ) : (
        <ScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            flexWrap: "wrap",
          }}
        >
          {tvData?.map((data: TVPROPS, index: number) => (
            <Poster
              key={index}
              data={data}
              watched={watched}
              setWatched={setWatched}
            />
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

and heres Poster.tsx:

```
type Props = {
  data: TVPROPS;
  watched: TVPROPS[];
  setWatched: any;
};

const Poster = ({ data, watched, setWatched }: Props) => {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [TVInfo, setTVInfo] = useState<any>();

  const handleClick = async () => {
    const response = await axios(
      `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${API_KEY}&i=${data.imdbID}`
    );
    const info = response.data;
    setTVInfo(info);
    setModalVisible(true);
  };

  const handleWatched = async () => {
    if (watched.includes(data)) {
      setWatched(
        watched.filter((favourite) => favourite.imdbID !== data.imdbID)
      );
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("react-watched", JSON.stringify(watched));
    } else {
      setWatched([data, ...watched]);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("react-watched", JSON.stringify(watched));
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Pressable
        style={{
          width: "32%",
          margin: 2,
          backgroundColor: "slategrey",
          borderRadius: 10,
          padding: 2,
        }}
        onPress={() => handleClick()}
      >
        <View>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "white" }}>
            {data?.Year}
          </Text>
          <Image
            source={{ uri: data?.Poster }}
            style={{
              width: 100,
              height: 150,
              alignSelf: "center",
              margin: 2,
            }}
          />
          <Text style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "white" }}>
            {data?.Title}
          </Text>
          <View style={{ alignSelf: "baseline", width: "100%" }}>
            <Button
              title={watched.includes(data) ? "Remove" : "Add"}
              onPress={() => handleWatched()}
            ></Button>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Pressable>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            borderRadius: 10,
            marginTop: "25%",
            padding: 10,
            backgroundColor: "white",
            margin: 20,
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, textAlign: "center" }}>
            {TVInfo?.Title}
          </Text>
          <Image
            source={{ uri: TVInfo?.Poster }}
            style={{
              width: 200,
              height: 300,
              alignSelf: "center",
            }}
          />
          <Text>Year: {TVInfo?.Year}</Text>
          <Text>Rating: {TVInfo?.Rated}</Text>
          <Text>Genre: {TVInfo?.Genre}</Text>
          <Text>Language: {TVInfo?.Language}</Text>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{TVInfo?.Plot}</Text>
          <Text>Metascore: {TVInfo?.Metascore}</Text>
          <Pressable
            onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
          >
            <Text>
              Close
            </Text>
          </Pressable>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default Poster;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    saveToLocalStorage(watched);
  }, [watched]);
```

When your component mounts for the first time `watched` is an empty array. Then your effect runs to retrieve the data from storage and set it. Then the above effect runs, and the original intention was probably to ensure the store stays in sync with `watched`.

However, on the first mount, this will overwrite the storage with that initial empty array. This is because whenever you call a set state operation, it doesn't change the value of the state immediately, it queues it for the next render. That means this second effect (which is run inside the same render, including on mount) sees `[]` as the value of `watched` even though the top effect ran before. There's also that `getLocalStorage` is asynchronous so that nails down the point that by the time this second effect runs, the data hasn't been set into watched yet. But this code wouldn't work anyway even if it was synchronous, because of the above point about how react sees state between effects within a single render.

For the setting of the storage, you probably want to do it in the event handler of what manipulates the todos and not in an effect. [See the react docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/removing-effect-dependencies#should-this-code-move-to-an-event-handler).

```
interface TVPROPS {
  Poster: string;
  Title: string;
  Type: string;
  Year: string;
  imdbID: string;
}

export default function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState<string>("");
  const [tvData, setTVData] = useState([]);
  const [watched, setWatched] = useState<TVPROPS[]>([]);
  const [watchClick, setWatchClick] = useState<Boolean>(false);

  const saveToLocalStorage = async (items: TVPROPS[]) => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("react-watched", JSON.stringify(items));
  };

  const getLocalStorage = async () => {
    const movieFavourites = await AsyncStorage.getItem("react-watched");
    if (movieFavourites !== null) {
      const movieFavouritesParse: TVPROPS[] = JSON.parse(movieFavourites);
      setWatched(movieFavouritesParse);
    }
  };

  const handleSearch = async (searchInput: string) => {
    const response = await axios(
      `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${API_KEY}&s=${searchInput}`
    );
    const data = response.data;
    setTVData(data.Search);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getLocalStorage();
  }, []);

  const handleSetWatched = (items: TVPROPS[]) => {
      setWatched(items);
      saveToLocalStorage(items);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: "grey" }}>
        <View style={{ marginTop: 40 }}>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", padding: 10 }}>
            <View
              style={{
                width: "50%",
                borderBottomWidth: watchClick ? 0 : 1,
                padding: 10,
                borderColor: "white",
              }}
            >
              <Pressable onPress={() => setWatchClick(false)}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    textAlign: "center",
                    color: watchClick ? "black" : "white",
                  }}
                >
                  Search
                </Text>
              </Pressable>
            </View>
            <View
              style={{
                width: "50%",
                borderBottomWidth: watchClick ? 1 : 0,
                padding: 10,
                borderColor: "white",
              }}
            >
              <Pressable onPress={() => setWatchClick(true)}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    textAlign: "center",
                    color: watchClick ? "white" : "black",
                  }}
                >
                  Watched
                </Text>
              </Pressable>
            </View>
          </View>
          <TextInput
            style={{ textAlign: "center" }}
            onChangeText={(text) => setSearch(text)}
            placeholder="Film or TV Show"
          ></TextInput>
          <Button onPress={() => handleSearch(search)} title="Search" />
        </View>
      </View>
      {watchClick ? (
        <ScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            flexWrap: "wrap",
          }}
        >
          {watched
            ?.filter((w) => w.Title.includes(search))
            .map((data: TVPROPS, index: number) => (
              <Poster
                key={index}
                data={data}
                watched={watched}
                setWatched={handleSetWatched}
              />
            ))}
        </ScrollView>
      ) : (
        <ScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            flexWrap: "wrap",
          }}
        >
          {tvData?.map((data: TVPROPS, index: number) => (
            <Poster
              key={index}
              data={data}
              watched={watched}
              setWatched={handleSetWatched}
            />
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seems to have solved my first problem. Just need to figure out why my button text isn't changing on the poster component during a search query

Comment: @Liiaam93 I know why. Its because `includes` only does comparison by reference, like "is this exact copy of the object inside of watched". If there's an object in there that is a different copy but has the same contents, it will still return false. This is the case since the ones in the search return are their own objects to the one in `watched`. They have the same content but that doesn't make the "same" as far as JS is concerned.

Comment: If each item in `tvData` has a unique identifier (check its contents coming back from API) you would instead do `watched.some(w => w.id === data.id)` or similar

Comment: Let me know if it has the ID and I will update the answer. May be able to form an id from some other properties also.

Comment: yes each one has a unique imdb-ID.

Comment: Amazing! had no idea about some() thanks again!